# Valid Parentheses Algorithm Effeciency

Tags: javascript, algorithm, balanced-delimiters

What do you think of my Algorithm?

I start to eliminate the nearest valid parentheses

and if `string.length == 0` so it's valid

```js
/**
 * @param {string} s
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var isValid = function(s) {
    while (s.length != 0 && s.includes("[]") || s.includes("()") || s.includes("{}")) {
        s = s.replace("[]", "");
        s = s.replace("()", "");
        s = s.replace("{}", "");
    }
    return s.length < 1
};

console.log(isValid("({((}{}))})"));
console.log(isValid("({(())})"));
```

Answer (score 5):

It's correct, but it's ineffiecent. It uses `O(n^2)` time in the worst case (for instance, if the input's `((((((..)))))))`).

You can do better than that by iterating over the input string and keeping a stack of brackets, pushing opening brackets to it and popping when you encounter closign brackets, checking that it's not empty and that the top bracket matches the current one.

Comment: Can you provide js code example please? I didn't get the idea clearly of your implementation

Comment: I didn't understand from where you got  O(n^2)  ? ? it's O(n)

Comment: @badr replace is `O(n)`. It's called `O(n)` times.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the other answer, you can simply loop through the string, keep track of the openers in an array (the stack), and if you find a closer, pop the stack to see if they match.

```js
const openers = {
  '{': true,
  '[': true,
  '(': true,
}

const closers = {
  '}': true,
  ']': true,
  ')': true,
}

const pairs = {
  '}': '{',
  ']': '[',
  ')': '(',
}

const areParensBalanced = string => {
  for(var stack = []; string.length; string = string.slice(1)){
    const next = string.charAt(0)
    const isOpener = openers[next]
    const isCloser = closers[next]
    
    // If it's not a parens at all
    if(!isOpener && !isCloser) return false
    
    // If it's a closer, but there's no more openers in the stack
    if(isCloser && !stack.length) return false
    
    // If it's a closer, match it with the recent opener
    if(isCloser && pairs[next] !== stack.pop()) return false

    // If it's an opener, push it to the stack
    if(isOpener) stack.push(next)
  }

  // We reached the end of the loop but not return.
  // Check if the stack has unclosed openers.
  return !Boolean(stack.length)
}

console.log(areParensBalanced("({((}{}))})"));
console.log(areParensBalanced("({(())})"));
```

Few things to note in your code:

- The complexity is `O(n^2)` because `while` is one loop, *`includes`* is another, making it a "loop inside a loop" scenario.
- You will need a lot of tests to make sure every combination is covered, not just the two logs you have.
- `isValid` is a vague function name for this functionality. You might want to name it `areParensBalanced`.
- Your code is doing unnecessary `string.replace()` operations when the string might not actually contain what you want to replace. You can at least just loop based on length, and do an `if` inside to see if that pair exists before doing the replace.
- Your code does not account for anything else other than a parens. Not sure if this is a feature, but just saying.

Comment: I don't really understand this line ` if(isCloser && pairs[next] !== stack.pop()) return false`

Comment: @Microsmsm If the next character is a closing parens and the top of the stack (the latest opening parens found) is not a matching open parens (mismatching open and close). `array.pop()` removes and returns the last item from the array, or in stack terms "the top of the stack".